# Open Datareader causing error and not pulling correct information

Tags: c#, sql, database, wpf, sqldatareader

I am not sure how to correct the error of having an open DataReader, if I close it then it throws a fits. I have tried changing the command names as well as other names to prevent this issue, but it seems to be persistent. That is the first issue, the second issue is I am not able to pull the correct data from my list. When I pass the information from the database to the list it should be in columns of FirstName to the First Name list, then Middle Initials and so on. I feel like that might be an issue with the command string q.

I have tried this in multiple different ways, but none of it seems to be working. I have changed reader names, tried to close and open as needed. As for the pulling data I have tried to change the command string q, I have tried to pass the information differently.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data.Sql;
using System.Windows.Forms;




namespace DEITO
{

/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for Customers.xaml
/// </summary>

public partial class Customers : Window
{




    public static List<String> CustomerFirstName = new List<string>();
    List<String> CustomerMiddleInitial = new List<string>();
    List<String> CustomerLastName = new List<string>();
    List<String> CustomerTaxClass = new List<string>();
    List<String> CustomerEmail = new List<string>();


    public Customers()
    {
        InitializeComponent();


        RetriveCustomerInfo();



    }




    public static string name;


    private List<String> RetriveCustomerInfo()
    {

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        try
        {


            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\SCook\Documents\LoginInformation.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30");

            con.Open();




            string q = "SELECT * FROM CustomerInfo";
            SqlCommand Comm = new SqlCommand(q, con);

           // SqlDataAdapter DAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter();



            SqlDataReader ReadThis = Comm.ExecuteReader();

            int Readerint = 0;


            while (ReadThis.Read())
            {





               // int StringCount = 0;


                name = ReadThis.GetString(1);
                //string MN = Reader.GetString(StringCount);
                //string LN = Reader.GetString(StringCount);
                //string TC = Reader.GetString(StringCount);
                //string EM = Reader.GetString(StringCount);

                CustomerFirstName.Add(name);
                //CustomerMiddleInitial.Add(MN);
                //CustomerLastName.Add(LN);
                //CustomerTaxClass.Add(TC);
                //CustomerEmail.Add(EM);

                // cmd..Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@FMT", name);







                Comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
                Comm.Parameters.Clear();
                con.Close();

                Readerint = Readerint + 1;
            }








        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {


            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);

        }







        /*string output = string.Join("\n", CustomerFirstName);
        string Out1 = string.Join("\n", CustomerMiddleInitial);
        string Out2 = string.Join("\n", CustomerLastName);
        string Out3 = string.Join("\n", CustomerTaxClass);
        string Out4 = string.Join("\n", CustomerEmail);
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(output); */



        return CustomerFirstName;

    }


    private void Exit_Clicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        this.Close();

    }

    public class CustomerInformation
    {

        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string MiddleInital { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string TaxClass { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }

    }


    public  void FillDataGridWithCustInfo()
    {

        int ArrayNum = 0;

        Int32 length = CustomerFirstName.Count;

        while (length >= ArrayNum)
        {




            CustomerInformation TempCust = new CustomerInformation();
            TempCust.FirstName = name;

            CustomerDataGrid.Items.Add(TempCust);




            ArrayNum = ArrayNum + 1;

        }





    }

    private void AddnewCustomer_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        CustomerInformation TempCust = new CustomerInformation();
        TempCust.FirstName = FirstNameText.Text;
        TempCust.MiddleInital = MiddleInitalText.Text;
        TempCust.LastName = LastNameText.Text;
        TempCust.TaxClass = TaxClassText.Text;
        TempCust.Email = EmailText.Text;

        CustomerDataGrid.Items.Add(TempCust);





        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\SCook\Documents\LoginInformation.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30");

        con.Open();

        string q = "insert into CustomerInfo (FirstName, MiddleInital, LastName, TaxClass, Email) Values(@FMT, @MIT, @LNT, @TCT, @EMT)";
        SqlCommand Comm = new SqlCommand(q, con);
        Comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FMT", FirstNameText.Text);
        Comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MIT", MiddleInitalText.Text);
        Comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LNT", LastNameText.Text);
        Comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TCT", TaxClassText.Text);
        Comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EMT", EmailText.Text);

        Comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
        Comm.Parameters.Clear();
        con.Close();


        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("You have successfully added to the database");


    }




    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {


        //RetriveCustomerInfo();


    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {


        FillDataGridWithCustInfo();

    }
  }
}
```

I am trying to take the data from database CustomerInfo and fill it into CustomerDataGrid. This seems like it should be less complex than I am making it out to be, but SQL is not my favorite language to have to deal with. When I change the .getstring(some Number) from 0 to 1 it is only pulling from the first row of data. so instead of giving me the first name of the next person down it will give me the middle initial.

Exception message: There is already an open datareader associated with this command which must be closed first.

Comment: I think you should understand better, how the `SqlDataReader`works: [Retrieve data using a DataReader](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/retrieving-data-using-a-datareader). Each call of the `Read` method get the next row from the database (as long as the call returns true). And you cannot execute the nextanother command on the database connection before you close the current `SqlDataReader`.

Comment: I understand I can't have more than 1 dataReader open at a time, but there is only one in this bit of code. Does it stay open from previous windows in WPF?

Comment: Your Insert instruction may not be working if your table has a primary key.   The instruction Comm.ExecuteNonQuery(); returns an integer indicating the number of rows changed.  Make sure you are not getting zero which indicates the value is already in the database.  I would use SQL Server Management Studio to verify you are inserting the data correctly.  Use "Select * from CustomerInfo" to dump the values.

Comment: Inserting the values have no issues at all though. They go in just fine and stay and fill to the proper place. it's just getting that information from the database.

Comment: Okay so I followed the link and I got the error to go away. I'm closing out the reader, but you say it keeps getting the rows of the database, but why is it only displaying the same thing over and over. let's say there are 4 First names in the database (John, Sue, Lucy, and Charlie). It reads their are 4 in their, but only inserts John into the datagrid 4 times.

Comment: It's the last name, not the first. You iterate the collection and it looks like you're going to use each item to set properties on tempcust. But you don't. Name has scope for the class and is set in retrievecustomerinfo. For each row read.   I recommend using an orm or micro orm. Dapper is quite close to the ado metal and obviates all the nasty boxing and unboxing code.